# order of before_filters in Rails controller and concerns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, actioncontroller, before-filter, activesupport-concern

I have a Rails concern defined as follows:

```
module MyConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_filter :filter_inside_concern
  end

  def filter_inside_concern
    # ...
  end
end
```

and I have a `before_filter` also on the controller layer:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :filter_inside_controller
end
```

If I include `MyConcern` inside `MyController`, does the order in which the before filters are called dependent on how the code is arranged? For example, if we have

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  include MyConcern

  before_filter :filter_inside_controller
end
```

Does `filter_inside_concern` gets called before `filter_inside_controller` (or vice versa)?

Thank you!

Comment: I think you can determine that yourself by adding log code in both filters and you can see the sequence in which its called. Give it a shot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have recreated your situation and find out sequence of execution depends on sequence in which you write both filters.

if you write

```
  include MyConcern
  before_filter :filter_inside_controller
```

concern filter will execute first

or if you write filters in this sequence

```
  before_filter :filter_inside_controller
  include MyConcern
```

controller filter will execute first

Comment: This is what i would expect intuitively, but i've found odd results with this sort of thing before and it's always worth checking via logging.

Comment: I have checked it via logging and got these results. when we include concern it injects `included` part of code where we write `include`.  Filter precedence is top to bottom which filter is on top executes first.

Comment: I'm sure, my comment was addressed to the poster really.

Answer (score 1):

If you use:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  include MyConcern

  before_filter :filter_inside_controller
end
```

`filter_inside_concern` will get called before `filter_inside_controller`

If you want to have `filter_inside_controller` called before `filter_inside_concern`, you need to use `prepend_before_filter` instead:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  include MyConcern

  prepend_before_filter :filter_inside_controller
end
```

As a side note, `before_filter` and `prepend_before_filter` will be deprecated. You should use `before_action` and `prepend_before_action` instead.